# Using ibid. with the biblatex Bath Harvard style

Tags: biblatex

I am new to Latex and am using the [`biblatex` Bath Harvard referencing style](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-bath).

It's a really nice style and does pretty much everything I want except one thing: I'd like to replace duplicated references with ibid.

Is there an easy way for me to do this, as a relative beginner, or am I better off switching to an alternative style, such as `authoryear-ibid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-bath`'s citation style is based on `authoryear-comp` and only adds about 15 lines of modifications ([see `biblatex-bath.dtx`, ll. 4196-4251](https://github.com/alex-ball/bathbib/blob/2d83989dcf38518b7ab0a616d208b3409f0edea6/biblatex/biblatex-bath.dtx#L4196-L4251)). This means that we can just load `authoryear-icomp` (the 'ibid' version of `authoryear-comp`) as citation style and add the modifications from `bath.cbx` directly to the preamble of your document.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=bath, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{uniquename=init}
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}%
}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {bbx:nonodate}
    and
    not test {\iflabeldateisdate}}%
}{}{\wlog{WARNING: biblatex-bath failed to patch cite:labeldate+extradate}}
\providetoggle{bbx:labelistitle}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite:label}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
  \toggletrue{bbx:labelistitle}%
}{}{\wlog{WARNING: biblatex-bath failed to patch cite:label}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite{worman}
sit \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998) ipsum (ibid.) dolor (Worman, 2002) sit (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998)]

If you plan to modify the style even further you may be better off using one of the standard styles after all.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly.

Comment: @KevinMiddleton If this answer solved your question, please consider accepting it - that (and voting) is the preferred way to say thank you on this site. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/35864